# Как в данном случае работает фрагмент кода?

Tags: javascript, html, hidden

При желании код ниже можно не смотреть,мне не понятна только строка (1)
Идя по цепочки родителей вверх,в свой свойство hidden  записывают наоборот  свойство не скрывающее узел? Цель задания:Дан список сообщений. Добавьте каждому сообщению кнопку для его удаления.
Используйте делегирование событий. Один обработчик для всего.

```css
body {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 470px;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: .3em;
  padding-right: 20px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 .5em;
}

.pane {
  background: #edf5e1;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px;
  border-top: solid 2px #c4df9b;
  position: relative;
}

.remove-button {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 110%;
  top: 0;
  color: darkred;
  right: 10px;
  display: block;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="messages.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="messages-container">
    <div class="pane">
      <h3>Лошадь</h3>
      <p>Домашняя лошадь — животное семейства непарнокопытных, одомашненный и единственный сохранившийся подвид дикой лошади, вымершей в дикой природе, за исключением небольшой популяции лошади Пржевальского.</p>
      <button class="remove-button">[x]</button>
    </div>
    <div class="pane">
      <h3>Осёл</h3>
      <p>Домашний осёл или ишак — одомашненный подвид дикого осла, сыгравший важную историческую роль в развитии хозяйства и культуры человека. Все одомашненные ослы относятся к африканским ослам.</p>
      <button class="remove-button">[x]</button>
    </div>
    <div class="pane">
      <h3>Корова, а также пара слов о диком быке, о волах и о тёлках. </h3>
      <p>Коро́ва — самка домашнего быка, одомашненного подвида дикого быка, парнокопытного жвачного животного семейства полорогих. Самцы вида называются быками, молодняк — телятами, кастрированные самцы — волами. Молодых (до первой стельности) самок называют
        тёлками.
      </p>
      <button class="remove-button">[x]</button>
    </div>
  </div>



  <script>
    var container = document.getElementById('messages-container');

    container.onclick = function(event) {
      if (!event.target.classList.contains('remove-button')) return;

      event.target.parentNode.hidden = !event.target.parentNode.hidden; // (1)
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Немного не понятно, в чем вопрос?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
event.target.closest(".pane").hidden = true;
```

Comment: правильно я понял ! перед elem преобразует в boolean ответе пожалуйста ?

Comment: @Leks `event.target.parentNode.hidden` уже является булевским значением, так что `!` просто меняет его на противоположное.

Comment: ясно спасибо, профессор :)

Comment: С возвращением!)

Comment: Igor ваш вариант покрайней мере я сразу понял.Но  и спасибо за разъяснение  по строке 1

Comment: @ZdraviSmisl На здоровье. Успехов!

Comment: @Дмытрык Спасибо. Сменил место работы - было не до ruSO.